# Show Json Value Consecutively with Material-UI Transition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I have an array of json that comes from the API.

```
"fruits": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "fruit": "APPLE",
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "fruit": "BANANA",
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "fruit": "CHERRY",
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "fruit": "GRAPE",
    }
  ]
```

I want to show the `fruit`s consecutively with `Material-UI` `Fade` transition.

First `fruit` should appear, then it should disappear, afterwards, next `fruit` should appear and disappear.
When all `fruit`s have been shown, it should start from the beginning.

How can I achieve this?

Something like this:

```
{fruit && fruit.map((item) =>(
  <Fade in={x} >
    <div className={styles.fruitContainer}>
      <p className={styles.fruitName}>{item.fruit}</p>
    </div>
  </Fade>
))}
```

**P.S.: Fruit amount(object amount) could vary.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React from "react";
import Fade from "@material-ui/core/Fade";

export default function SimpleFade() {
  const [id, setId] = React.useState(1);

  const data = {
    fruits: [
      {
        id: "1",
        fruit: "APPLE"
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        fruit: "BANANA"
      },
      {
        id: "3",
        fruit: "CHERRY"
      },
      {
        id: "4",
        fruit: "GRAPE"
      }
    ]
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setId((prevId) => (prevId < data.fruits.length ? prevId + 1 : 1));
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [data.fruits.length]);

  return (
    <div>
      {data.fruits.map((fruit) => (
        <Fade in={parseInt(fruit.id, 10) === id} key={`fader_${fruit.id}`}>
          <p>{fruit.fruit}</p>
        </Fade>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-m2xvg?file=/demo.js

Something like this? Styling is required if they need to be in the same place.

Comment: Yes, perfect. Thank you so much for your time. I want them to be in the same place. `position:'absolute'` didn't work. Do you have any idea how I can put them in the same place?

Comment: `Fade` transition cannot be seen actually, `in` parameter changes cannot correct the `Fade` transition. Is there a way to slow down the transitions?

Comment: The animation time can be set via timeout parameter, for example:
`<Fade in={parseInt(fruit.id, 10) === id} key={\`fader_${fruit.id}\`} timeout={{ enter: 1000, exit: 1000 }}>`

Comment: For styling, try adding both `position: 'absolute'` and `top: 0px`, not sure if that's the best solution for your use-case, but that works for the example.